# Collision in Merkle–Damgård without a collision in compression function

Tags: collision-resistance, merkle-damgaard

Is it possible to find a collision in Merkle–Damgård  just by omitting the extra one bit that is appended to each input without having a collision in compression function?

Comment: I don't think so -- the length suffix should be enough to make the reduction work.

Comment: @CodesInChaos It would be interesting to know what you make of bilge's answer.

Comment: No, you don't need any extra bits. It is sufficient that the padding function be suffix-free (one possibility to get a suffix-free padding is to append the length of the message as the last block). This was shown independently by both Merkle and Damgard at CRYPTO'89 for a specific suffix-free padding, and later generalized by Andreeva et al. in "Security Reductions of the Second Round SHA-3 Candidates". The proof was also carried out mechanically in [Verified Security of Merkle-Damgard](http://www.infsec.cs.uni-saarland.de/~berg/publications/berg12indiffmd.pdf), which I co-authored ;-)

Comment: @owlstead That answer make an incorrect assumption about the padding.

Comment: @MalteSkoruppa Suffix free is not a sufficient requirement for the padding. If you can find an input that hashes to the IV, then you can prepend that input to any string in order to generate a collision without having a collision in the compression function.

Comment: @kasperd This is incorrect, the assumption of a suffix-free padding function precludes that possibility. Formally, consider a message $m$ such that $H(m)=IV$, as you say. Now you are saying that we get $H(m||m')=H(m')$ for any $m'$. This is because you implicitly assume that the padding of $m'$ is a suffix of the padding of $m||m'$ and, therefore, since the MD iteration will hash $m$ onto $IV$, the rest of the iteration will behave as if it had only hashed $m'$ in the first place. However, if the padding is suffix-free, then the padding of $m'$ will *not* be a suffix of the padding of $m||m'$.

Comment: Or think about it this way: what would you tell me if I said that appending the length of the original message was not enough, because if I find a message that hashes to the IV, then I could prepend any string to that message in order to get a collision? Right, you would tell me that no, the last block will be different, because the length is not the same, so with high probability we don't get a collision. That's the point: with a suffix-free padding, some of the blocks of the padding of $m'$ must differ from the last blocks of the padding of $m||m'$. It just need not be the *last* block.

Comment: @MalteSkoruppa In my previous message I said you could prepend the message, I should have said you can prepend the padded version of the message. So if $H(m) = IV$, then for any message $m'$ we have $H(m||padding(m)||m')=H(m')$. In this case we don't need padding on one message to be a suffix of padding on the other, rather we just need the padding on both to be identical. In other words $padding(m||padding(m)||m')=padding(m')$.

Comment: @kasperd We may be thinking of different meanings of the term "padding" here, and thus simply misunderstand each other. For me a "padding function" is a function that splits a message into a list of fixed-size blocks. Hence, the type of $padding$ is something like $\{0,1\}^*\rightarrow(\{0,1\}^k)^*$. So for me your last comment does not even type ;-) It would be my pleasure if you could read the beginning of Section III of my paper above (until Definition 4), where this is precisely defined (very short!). Under these definitions, would you still say that a suffix-free padding is not enough?

Comment: @MalteSkoruppa That makes sense. If the set of padded messages is suffix free, then there cannot be collisions in the hash function without collisions in the compression function. If padding had simply been a one bit followed by a sequence of zero bits (without the length field in the end), then the padding itself would be suffix free, but collision resistance wouldn't be guaranteed.

Comment: @kasperd Yes I perfectly agree -- glad we could clear this up. :-)

Comment: Also @owlstead I was previously about to write an answer, but kasperd beat me to it and I was happy with his. An answer of mine would have been much more formal, anyway (I was about to write a very mathematical proof under the assumption of a suffix-free padding function), and I thought that most people here would probably prefer his somewhat more intuitive explanation. :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, it is not possible.

If two inputs with different length produce identical hash outputs, then there would be a collision in the last invocation of the compression function. This is because the last input to the compression function always encodes the length of the original message.

If two inputs with identical length produce identical hash outputs, then there would be a collision in the compression function somewhere along the way. This is because considering the entire Merkle-Damgård hash as a hash tree build up of invocations of the compression function, then you will get two trees with identical structure, but those two trees have different inputs and identical output. By induction it can be shown that at least one of the invocations of the compression function in that tree structure must have a collision.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, of course it is possible. Let's consider with below example:

Our compression function: $f:\{0,1\}^{(128+512+1)} → \{0,1\}^{128}$

Message $x$ has 1000 bits: ($y$'s are our input blocks and $z$'s are output blocks. Considered a Merkle–Damgård construction.)

- $y_1$ is first 512 bits of $x$
- $y_2$ is last 488 bits of $x||0^{24}$
- $y_3$ is $0^{480}||“32-bit\ binary\ representation\ of\ 24”$

Iteration results:

- $z_1 = f(0^{129}||y_1)$ where $z_1$ has 128 bits
- $z_2 = f(z_1||1||y_2)$
- $z_3 = f(z_2||1||y_3)$ where $z_3$ is the message digest $h(x)$

Now suppose that message $x′$ has 488 bits and $h(x)=h(x′)$ … there is a collision for $h$:

- $y_1′$ is $x′||0^{24}$
- $y_2′$ is $0^{480}||“32-bit\ binary\ representation\ of\ 24”$
- $z_1' = f(0^{129}||y_1')$ where $z_1$ has 128 bits
- $z_2' = f(z_1||1||y_2')$ where $z_2$ is $h(x)$

Then $f(z_1'||1||y_2')=f(z_2||1||y_3)$ and $y_3=y_2'$

- if $z_1′ \neq z_2$ then a collision is found for $f$
- if $z_1' = z_2$ then $f(0^{129}||y_1') = f(z_1||1||y_2)$, there is also a collision for $f$

For our above example – if there is a collision, it can only be in our $f$ function. But, if you erase $1$ for each input you'll get collision in your inputs.

Comment: Welcome to crypto.SE! $\;$ Is your claim that SHA-1 without insertion of the extra 1 bit is breakable? Are you exhibiting an explicit collision? If yes, what are the two colliding messages? $\;$ I'm trying to follow you, but fail. If guess you mean $f:\{0,1\}^{128+512+1}\to\{0,1\}^{128}$ (written `$f:\{0,1\}^{128+512+1}\to\{0,1\}^{128}$` on this nice website, which handles a subset of $\TeX$), but then I'm getting lost; what's $y$, why does the binary representation of 24 matters (I get that $24=512-488$ but fail to see the significance), what is $z$, what is "z1=f 0^129||y1 z1" meaning?

Comment: yi =(y1,y2,..yn) are our input blocks and zi = (z1, z2,..., zn) are out blocks when we consider schema of Merkle-Damgard.I'm new that's why I don't know how to use it properly, yet. f is our function I forgot ()'s add. binary representation of 24 is matter because of shows if y2' and y3 are equal, we can calculate and see there is something wrong in f function.

Comment: It is not clear to me what kind of padding function you are using here - why do you always append $0^{480}||“32-bit\ binary\ representation\ of\ 24”$ as the last block, independently of the message length? What seems clear is that your padding function is not suffix-free - if $x'$ equals the last 488 bits of $x$, then $pad(x')$ is a suffix of $pad(x)$. The strengthened Merkle-Damgard iteration however prescribes a suffix-free padding function. Only under this assumption is the "collision-resistance" of $f$ preserved by the Merkle-Damgard iteration.

Comment: Your padding is incorrect. The correct padding ends with the length of the message (measured in bits). Thus since $1000 \neq 488$ it follows that $y3 \neq y2'$.